# R: Generate sequence of powers of ten

Tags: r

How do you generate the sequence of numbers 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ... quickly/efficiently in R?

I know `seq` can give you a sequence of numbers separated by some interval, but is there a function that can give you powers of a number?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
10^(0:10)
#  [1] 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02 1e+03 1e+04 1e+05 1e+06 1e+07 1e+08 1e+09 1e+10
```