# How to make sequence raising a number to a sequence of powers

Tags: r, sequence, seq

I have:

```
cost = c(2^(-5),2^(-3),2^(-1),2^(1),2^(3),2^(5),2^(7),2^(9),2^(11),2^(13),2^(15))
```

and I would like a more elegant command, such as:

```
seq(from = 2^(-5), to = 2^(15), by = __)
```

Comment: `2^seq(from = -5, to = 15, by = 2)`

Comment: Nice question, short but complete, to the point.

Comment: Related: [R: Generate sequence of powers of ten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766471/r-generate-sequence-of-powers-of-ten)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` is vectorized in both arguments, so you can raise `2` to your nicely linear sequence of powers:

```
2^seq(from = -5, to = 15, by = 2)
```

Comment: when I tried at 2am, I kept trying a completely different sleep deprived way. :)